# react page doesn't load on ubuntu but does on local wsl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, react-hooks, react-router

I'm having a strange issue where code that works perfectly on my local and runs without any issues doesn't work on an ubuntu server

When running `npm start`, my local shows "Compiled successfully!" while the server shows "Compiled with warnings." and a whole laundry list of issues

The console of my local shows nothing, no errors. The server shows all of the following errors:
[image: errors]

### None of these errors are present on my local

Things I've tried:

1. I made sure both node versions were on their latest (18.x)
2. All packages are up to date and installed

I'm simply lost as to what the solution would be

Comment: How did you send the files to the server? Did you copy `node_modules`?

Comment: @Konrad I just did a `git pull` on the branch that I wanted to test, and then ran `npm install` before `npm start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to install the `styled-components` library when the program is entirely made up of styled components, in addition to updating npm :facepalm: